# Why v4.9.3 of node-sass not exist?

Tags: node.js, angular, npm

I learn Angular from Pluralsight. So I clone this project [Angular-GettingStarted](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted) from GitHub.

when I install the package (`npm i`) the npm try to download `https://github.com/sass/node-sass/releases/download/v4.9.3/win32-x64-67_binding.node` but got 404 error.

Why? I can see its part of [@angular-devkit/build-angular](https://github.com/DeborahK/Angular-GettingStarted/blob/master/APM-Start/package-lock.json#L6602).

I need these packages exactly for my practice.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to rebuild your node-sass:

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```